# How to use DP variable response code in xslt?

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, ibm-datapower

Can someone explain me what is happening in this code step by step ? why we are setting `x-dp-response-code value = -1` and what it returns ?

```
<xsl:variable name="responsecode" select="normalize-space(dp:response-header('x-dp-response-code'))"/>
        <dp:set-variable name="'var://context/service/responsecode'" value="$responsecode"/>
        <dp:set-response-header name="'x-dp-response-code'" value="'-1'"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume `value="$responsecode"/>` should be `value="{$responsecode}"/>`

For info on `<dp:set-response-header name="'x-dp-response-code'" value="'-1'"/>` see the [these docs of ibm](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/datapower-gateway/10.0.1?topic=functions-dphttp-response-header).

> The x-dp-response-code special code is a protocol response code. This
> special code is not a response header, but contains the
> protocol-specific response code.